# Подсветка синтаксиса в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, frontend, client

День добрый! Думаю, все видели онлайн редакторы, вроде DartPad, Fiddler и т.д. Плохо представляю, как подсвечивать слова внутри textarea и подобных элементов страницы. В офлайне хотя-бы была ясность с созданием кастомных контролов, но на счет HTML ничего не могу сказать. Гуглил, но либо предлагают полностью готовое решения, либо не то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день, вам нужно использовать html свойство **[contenteditable](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable)**, тогда думаю пазл у вас сложится.

Данное свойство поможет вам парсить введенные значения и обрамлять их тегами/классами и тд, там уж как вам угодно